# creating a top level span in python opentelemetry

Tags: python, python-asyncio, open-telemetry

I have a python service that I am trying to add opentelemetry to. I am manually tracking user requests and subtasks and this seems to work ok: I am able to look at the spans in jaeger.

However, my system may decide to start a background asyncio task in the middle of a request. The request will end immediately, but the background task will go on forever. If I track code called by this task as spans, they end up being children of the request's span, although the request already ended. I'd rather prefer to show these spans as top level, like not children of any parent.

The documentation seems not to address this specific case, so I am trying to find the way

This is a simplified version of what I am attempting:

```py
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry import context

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
ROOT_CONTEXT = context.get_current()
tasks = set()

async def background_task(some_req_info):
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("background task", context=ROOT_CONTEXT):
        # do stuff
        ...

async def request(some_req_info):
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("request"):
        # more logic
        task = asyncio.create_task(background_task(some_req_info))
        tasks.add(task)
        task.add_done_callback(tasks.discard)
```

How can I achieve parent-less spans in background tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I was actually measuring the wrong thing in jaeger. The code I posted works as expected. I am leaving this question here to save hours to the next developer wanting to solve this particular problem.

Comment: What problem and what were you actually measuring? I'm using OTEL and Jaeger too, and I can't understand the problem. In fact, you probably *want* the background task to be related to the parent trace or span that spawned it. The whole point of tracing is to find what caused what, not measure steps. You can set the completion status of a Span explicitly instead depending on `with` to stop it.

Comment: Were you looking at the trace in Jaeger instead of the individual spans?

Comment: I was looking a different (but similar) span. A naming issue... :(

Comment: I Agree that I might want to know what caused the background job. However this is more like a lazy loading case: the request asks for a particular infrastructure to load, this means that from now on we need to maintain this infrastructure. however, the request enabling the particular infrastructure completed successfully.